# parent class cannot see child parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, asp.net-core, architecture

i have edited the question to be more clear. old question is below.

i have 2 child classes with their own implementation of a database client but still under the same parent database interface (ie such as repository pattern).

```
class Child1
{
  protected IDB_Child1 DB;
  public void Disconnect()
  {
    DB.disconnect();
  }
}
class Child2
{
  protected IDB_Child2 DB;
  public void Disconnect()
  {
    DB.Disconnect();
  }
}
interface IDB_Child1 : IDB {}
interface IDB_Child2 : IDB {}
interface IDB { void Disconnect() }
```

this works:

```
Child1 c1 = new Child1();
c1.Disconnect(); //OK
```

obviously i want to move the common functionality above to a parent, as the very basic refactoring step. i do:

```
abstract class Parent
{
  protected IDB DB;
  public void Disconnect()
  {
    DB.Disconnect();
  }
}

class Child1 : Parent
{
  protected IDB_Child1 DB;
}
class Child2 : Parent
{
  protected IDB_Child2 DB;
}
```

for some reason, C# has its own scope for such variables and i cannot access the DB from the parent class:

```
Child1 c1 = new Child1();
c1.Disconnect(); // ERROR: DB is null in the parent even though in the c1 it is initialized and visible from child1 class methods.
```

**how can i achieve such basic OOP functionality ?**

Comment: You redeclared `DB` in `Child` without assigning any value to it. Add `this.DB = database` to your ctor implementation.

Comment: Or dont redeclared DB and use for Child something like `protected IDB_Child DBChild => DB`

Comment: @SebastianSchumann that wont work because the parent method ```c.Foo()``` would access different DB variable than ```c.ChildFoo()```

Comment: Going back a step - why does `Parent` inherit from `Child` at all? It seems like you're making one class inherit from another and then trying to undo it by replacing the base class behavior. I don't think you should be using inheritance at all unless there's some reason not shown here.

Comment: @ScottHannen the reason is picking up the common functionality across several child classes. imagine i got the same DB disconnect function in all child classes. this same function is picked above into parent. but the parent cannot access the DB. am i breaking any clear OOP structures here? im talking about the very basics, and i cannot understand why C# is so problematic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like generics may get you what you want (assuming `IDB_Child` extends or implements `IDB`):

```
abstract class Parent<T>
{
  protected T DB;
  public void Disconnect()
  {
    DB.Disconnect();
  }
}

class Child1 : Parent<IDB_Child1>
{
}
class Child2 : Parent<IDB_Child2>
{
}
```

You could also use an accessor instead of inheriting a field:

```
abstract class Parent
{
  protected IDB DB() {get;}
  public void Disconnect()
  {
    getDB().Disconnect();
  }
}

class Child1 : Parent
{
  protected IDB_Child1 _DB;
  override IDB DB() 
  {  
      get 
      {
          return DB;
      }
  }
}
class Child2 : Parent
{
  protected IDB_Child2 _DB;
  override IDB DB() 
  {  
      get 
      {
          return DB;
      }
  }
}
```

> // ERROR: DB is null in the parent even though in the c1 it is initialized and visible from child1 class methods

That's because you've declared (but not initialized that you've shown) a *new* `DB` field in the child classes. Since the parent `DB` instance is visible to the children, you don't need to declare a different one.

Comment: thx for answer. i have made an edit to the question. could you please take a look again and confirm generics is the only way to go?

Comment: I've updated my answer to your new code. I still think you'll have more detail that you're not showing that will change the _best_ answer, but the key points are don't hide parent members and understand what is truly generic.

Comment: thanks for edit but that wont work at all. im feeling like a fool and desperate to explain. imagine the child interface to have additional methods specific to that child only: ```interface IDB_Child1 : IDB { void NEWMethod(); }```. if i will keep the ```DB``` param in the parent only, the compiler will fail at the child level with ```c1.NEWMethod();``` because all the child sees is the parents ```IDB``` param and not the ```IDB_Child1``` param with the method.

Comment: although the workaround with ```getDB()``` might work if i would retype each child implementation with ```IDB_Child DB()...``` instead of ```IDB DB()...``` as you did. but thats some hell of a workaround with creating the exact same lines of code duplicites accross all child classes, which is actually my very first issue that i want to avoid.

Comment: Well it's hard to provide a complete answer without the complete situation. If the child IDB classes have methods specific to them, then they can;t be used generically by the parent. There are other ways to handle that, though - using abstract methods in the parent and implementing them in the children, etc. Also don;t be completely afraid of duplicate code. Sometimes it's unavoidable in a strongly-typed system.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare DB in the child (you can access the one from Parent by inheritence). As a hint you had to use the new keyword because it was conflicting with the parent DB field (which is usally very bad).

Just remove

> new protected IDB_Child DB;

Here is a complete implementation:

```
public interface IDB
{
    void Bar();
}

abstract class Parent 
{
    protected IDB DB;
    public Parent(IDB database) {
        DB = database;
    }
    public void Foo()
    {
        DB.Bar();
    }
}
class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(IDBImplem database) : base(database) {}
    public void ChildFoo()
    {
        DB.Bar();
    }
}

public class IDBImplem : IDB
{
    public void Bar()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: that wont work. imagine i got Class1, Class2, Class3 each with their own DB implementation. they must have their own context of DB, but leaving the parameter in parent only would create only 1 variable, not 3.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how it works with an example of IDBImplem different in first child

Comment: @ulkas - in the scenario you're describing where each class has its own DB implementation, there's no reason for these classes to inherit from each other. Inheritance is often messy anyway, but in this case it sounds like it's giving you nothing and making things confusing. If you need a common type then these classes could all implement a common interface. But inheritance doesn't seem to make any sense here.

Comment: this one wont help either. imagine the implementation class to have specific: ```public class IDBImplem : IDB
{ public void Bar2() {} } ``` then calling the method ```Bar2()``` in the child class method ```ChildFoo()``` will raise a compiler error, since the ```DB``` param is of type ```IDB``` which does not contain ```Bar2``` method